# Get tap event Lock Screen Control(MPRemoteCommandCenter)

Tags: ios, swift, lockscreen, mpremotecommandcenter

I have implemented Avplayer for play audio. I have used  MPRemoteCommandCenter to get access on lock screen. I can get all access by:

```
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the pause command
        return .success
    }

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the play command
        return .success
    }
```

But I want to detect  when user taps on music title or logo or player from lock screen. It open our app. is It Possible to get?

I want to open a controller when user taps on music player from lock screen.

Comment: I have exactly the same question!

Answer (score 1):

You can respond when your app is activated, but there is no way to learn that it was activated because the user tapped on the music player in the lock screen.

Comment: Thanks @matt, When music player will be in lock screen its mean my app is in background. Just I want to know the tap event on music player.

Comment: And I told you that you cannot know. The end.

Comment: You can respond when your app is activated... You mean inside AppDelegate function `applicationDidBecomeActive` ?

Comment: That is one way, yes